# Counting the maximum row of a given number

Tags: python, counter

Write a program that generates 100 random integers that are either 0 or 1. Then find the
longest run of zeros, the largest number of zeros in a row. For instance, the longest run of
zeros in [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] is 4.

All explanations are in the code

```
import random

sequence = []

def define_sequence():
    for i in range(0,100):
        sequence.append(random.randint(0,1))
    print(sequence)
    return sequence
define_sequence()

def sequence_count():
    zero_count = 0 #counts the number of zeros so far
    max_zero_count = 0 #counts the maximum number of zeros seen so faz
    for i in sequence:
      if i == 0: #if i == 0 we increment both zero_count and max_zero_count
        zero_count += 1
        max_zero_count += 1
      else:
        zero_count = 0 #if i == 1 we reset the zero_count variable
        if i == 0:
          zero_count += 1 #if we see again zero we increment the zero_count variable again
          if zero_count > max_zero_count:
            max_zero_count = zero_count  #if the zero_count is more than the previous max_zero_count we assignt to max_zero_count the zero_count value
    return max_zero_count
print(sequence_count())
```

I expect the program to print the longest run of zeros and not the actual number of zeros in the generated list

Comment: And what problems do you have with the current approach?

Comment: As i said it is printing all the zeros in the list and not the longest run of zeros

Comment: Relevant / possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424729/how-to-find-run-length-encoding-in-python/43424784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, with the method you are using. Other people would give you the pythonic way:

```
import random
sequence = []
def define_sequence():
    for i in range(0,100):
        sequence.append(random.randint(0,1))
    print(sequence)
return sequence
define_sequence()
def sequence_count():
    zero_count = 0 #counts the number of zeros so far
    max_zero_count = 0 #counts the maximum number of zeros seen so faz
    for i in sequence:
        if i == 0: #if i == 0 we increment both zero_count and max_zero_count
            zero_count += 1
            if zero_count > max_zero_count:
                max_zero_count = zero_count  #if the zero_count is more than the previous max_zero_count we assignt to max_zero_count the zero_count value
        else:
            zero_count = 0 #if i == 1 we reset the zero_count variable
    return max_zero_count
print(sequence_count())
```

Answer (score 4):

As you said that there are only two numbers, `0` or `1`, so we will use this feature. Its simple and will work only with these numbers:

```
len(max("".join(map(str, a)).split("1")))
```

**Example:**

```
>>> a = [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
>>> 
>>> len(max("".join(map(str, a)).split("1")))
4
>>>
```

**Explanation:**

We are converting all the integer entries to string using [`map`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp), [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)ing it to get a string, & [`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)ting it on `1`. `split` uses `1` as delimiter and gives a list. After that, we are counting the length of the longest string in the list using [`len`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp). [`max`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_max.asp) returns the longest string from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
max(len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(lst) if k == 0)
```

where `lst` is your input list.

**Example**:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]

print(max(len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(lst) if k == 0))
# 4
```

Comment: i know my code could be much simpler. But what do you sugest me to do?

Comment: @LuísLopes, When you understand how `groupby` works, it's much much simpler than  your approach. Hence, I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
num = 0

max([len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(a) if k == num])
4
```